# Determine if Lossless using TagLib

Tags: vb.net, audio, taglib, taglib-sharp, lossless

I'm working on a little project for my own personal use in VB.NET which relates to multimedia (audio and video) files.

I've added TagLib to my project via NuGet, and am slowly finding ways to get the information from my files using it.

One thing i was wondering however, is if there's a way to determine if a file contains Lossless audio? Obviously some file formats are lossless, like WAV as an obvious example, but with formats like WMA, and AAC/ALAC often share the same extension with their lossy counterparts.

Therefore, does TagLib offer a method for determining with an audio stream within a file is lossless? If so, can you advise on how this can be achieved in VB.Net? I've had a look online but can unfortunately not find anything...

My primary reason for this relates to audio only files, so not necessarily video files, which could contain multiple audio tracks.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: `TagLib` is a tagging library. Thus it only contains tags which are specified. For determining things about the audio itself, I think `NAudio` might be useful...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check NAudio out. Hopefully it can do what i'm after...

Thanks again